# Using only a part of BMS' balance leads

Tags: batteries, bms

I was searching for a 100 ampere BMS.  I saw one that said: 6S-28S and I was wondering if it's possible to use only a few balance leads and how to do it.  Any other 10S BMS is either not capable of enduring 100A or too big for my usage.

Edit: [Here's the part](https://www.banggood.com/fr/6S-to-28S-100A-BMS-Battery-Protection-Board-with-Balancing-for-Electric-Motor-Car-PCM-18650-Battery-Pack-Lithium-Balance-Charging-Board-p-1658226.html?gmcCountry=FR&currency=EUR&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgs&utm_content=frank&utm_campaign=frank-ssc-fr-css-all-19cov-0403&ad_id=429902602762&gclid=Cj0KCQjwwr32BRD4ARIsAAJNf_0hGjYNDhbvCsVxW2oy861BtcZ9CnEij0krW4LtqSXSRvqjBWbfdlcaAn2MEALw_wcB)

Comment: You want us to go shopping for 10S-BMS ? Do you realize 100A is for discharge and 10A is for charge max?

Comment: "You want us to go shopping for 10S-BMS ?" No, i just want to know if the part i specified is capable of managing a 10s configuration and yes i need 100 A in discharge and 10amps is sufficient for charging

Comment: An ad with no datasheet isn't particularly useful for design purposes.  We'll need a link to the datasheet, I couldn't find it based on the part number in the photograph.